# Drawing multiple UIImageView's with the same ImageContext?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I want to draw 3 different images using Core Graphics, e.g. a rectangle (imageview1), a circle (imageview2) and a triangle (imageview3).

Currently, in my ViewController, my code looks like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create my rectangle
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(200, 100));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [[UIColor colorWithRed:237/255.0 green:247/255.0 blue:242/255.0 alpha:1.0] setFill];
    CGContextAddRect(context, CGRectInset(CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 10, 80), 0.0f, 0.0f));
    CGContextFillPath(context);

    UIImage *rectangle = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // create my ImageView
    UIImageView *rectangleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160, 40,      rectangle.size.width, rectangle.size.height)];
    legView.image = leg;

    // add my image view to parent view
    [self.view addSubview:legView];
}
```

So, if I want to continue creating more images, do I need to create a new context for every new image? E.g., CGContextRef context2, context3, etc etc.? It seems a bit unwieldly, but I'm a beginner so any tips appreciated!